# How to pass layout as a function argument

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arguments

It's possibly a really simple question but I am stuck with this one.

I have a function which is called many times in my application.
I want to refactor it but I don't know how to pass the value of `findViewById` as an argument.

Do you know how to do it, please?

```java
public void configureToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activitySettingsToolbar);
        mToolbar.setElevation(0);
        mToolbar.setTitle("");

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
```

EDIT:

So far, I can do this `configureToolbar(Activity activity, Toolbar mToolbar)` with this result:

```java
public void configureToolbar(Activity activity, Toolbar toolbar) {
       toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activitySettingsToolbar);
       toolbar.setElevation(0);
       toolbar.setTitle("");

       ((AppCompatActivity)activity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   }
```

But if I want to change my layout, I need to be able to pass it as an argument :/

Comment: `configureToolbar(Toolbar mToolBar)` ? and call it by `configureToolbar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.x))`

Comment: create the function like this `configureToolbar(Toolbar toolBar){ // function body}`

Comment: @AbidKhan it's java, not kotlin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could potentially pass through the ID of the toolbar :

```
public void configureToolbar(int id) {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(id);
    mToolbar.setElevation(0);
    mToolbar.setTitle("");

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

then you can call this with :

```
configureToolbar(R.id.yourToolbarId)// in your case this is R.id.activitySettingsToolbar or any other toolbar Id
```

---

After edit from OP :

```
 public void configureToolbar(Activity activity, int toolbarId) {
 Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) activity.findViewById(toolbarId);
   if(toolbar != null) { //credit to @Gabriele Mariotti, I missed this check
   toolbar.setElevation(0);
   toolbar.setTitle("");

   ((AppCompatActivity)activity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }
}
```

then you call this with :

```
configureToolbar(yourActivity, R.id.yourToolbarId)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
private void setupToolbar(int resource){
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(resource);
    if (toolbar != null){
      //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass layout in parameters is to use **@LayoutRes** anotation:

```
fun buildDialog(@LayoutRes viewId : Int) {

}
```